# why my images not load in carousal untill i open inspect tool?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

My carousal working properly .
But when image load it is not showing image perfectly . 
After opening of my inspect tool it shows me proper images .
So any one please help me with this problem . 
May be css and js are not load when carousal start . Css and Js load after open inspect tool .

https://www.vfes.in/

This is web link in events carousal part when click open new carousal in pop up menu,but after open inspect tool pop up carousal work properly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!:) For asking good question, I recommend you to read this guide:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To be clear we cannot read your mind or somehow access your computer to check for errors. Show us your js, html and css.

Comment: How we will understand. Paste your code in jsfiddle

Comment: i update my que so please check it and help me guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes issue found on js

```
owl-item cloned
```

this class  isn't update width when pop up is open. its only work when you will resize the browser. so you have to call same js on popup open event.

Comment: if possibe explain in details.